# Identificar qual página requisita outra através do require_once

Tags: php

Tenho um **header.php**, onde está contido meu page bar, que por sua vez possui o breadcrumb e também o que eu chamo de "Toolbar" que são os botões de ações relacionadas à página que está sendo acessada. Por exemplo:

Quando o usuário acessar o módulo "Clientes", ele acessará **client-list.php**, que faz um *require_once* no **header.php**.

O problema é que cada módulo terá botões diferentes, assim como o usuário terá permissões. Então ao acessar **client-list.php**, o **header.php** deve mostrar os botões relevantes à **client-list.php**, também considerando as permissões.

Como posso fazer para que meu **header.php** identifique qual página/módulo está chamando ele através do *require_once* para que ele mostre informações pertinentes à essa página/módulo?

Comment: Utilize variáveis de [sessão](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php) do PHP, assim poderá armazenar dados entre páginas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode em todos scripts de página criar uma constante assim:

```
<?php
define('PAGINA', basename(__FILE__));

require_once 'header.php';
```

E no **header.php** usar if, switch ou qualquer outra coisa, algo como:

```
<?php
switch (PAGINA) {
    case 'client-list.php':
        //Botões especificos para client-list
        break;

    case 'contato.php':
        //Botões especificos para contato
        break;

}
```

---

### Usando `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`

Para simplificar/facilitar pode ainda a variavel `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` dentro do **header.php** e não vai precisar fazer/adicionar nada nos outros scripts:

```
<?php
$pagina = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

switch (PAGINA) {
    case 'client-list.php':
        //Botões especificos para client-list
        break;

    case 'contato.php':
        //Botões especificos para contato
        break;

}
```